# Is the MERN stack considered serverless?

Tags: serverless, serverless-architecture

I am trying to understand the serverless architecture...

I recently went through a MERN stack course on Udemy. We created a simple MERN stack webapp. We then used [render.com](https://render.com/) to host the app. Is that considered serverless? To me, we used a *single file* for the backend. While that file is hosted on render, they are still linked together.

Does serverless mean that each function used by an app is hosted independent of the other functions?

I tried to describe my thoughts below, but not sure how to best describe it... Would appreciate any feedback.

*With Server*

All within a single file (Node.js) environment we have functions that upload images, query database for specific user data, delete posts, etc...

*Serverless*

Seperate files for each function. Hypothetically if I log into AWS Lambda (or whatever service), I would see a list of all my functions with a js file linked to that function.

Comment: [This article](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/cloud-native-apps/what-is-serverless) does a good job of describing serverless. Keep in mind that "serverless" is a marketing term.